# Unable to display my CreateForm in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a form and a view in Django and I'm trying to display it in the HTML but it isn't loading anything and I don't know why.

alumno2.html

```
{% block header %}
    <header class="masthead bg-white text-dark text-uppercase">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-center">Añadir alumno</h3>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

form.py

```
class AlumnoForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alumno
        #fields = ['dni', 'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2','email','repetidor']
        fields = ['dni', 'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2','email','repetidor','curs']

        labels = {
            'dni': 'dni',
            'nombre': 'nombre',
            'apellido1': 'Primer Apellido',
            'apellido2': 'Segundo Apellido',
            'email': 'Email',
            'repetidor': 'repetidor',
            'curs': 'curs'
        }

        widgets = {
            'dni': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'apellido1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'apellido2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'repetidor': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-checkbox','id': 'repetidor'}),
            'curs':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

view.py

```
class crea_alumno(CreateView):
    model = Alumno
    form_class = AlumnoForm2
    template_name = '/alumno2.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mostrar_alumnos')
```

url.py

```
url(r'^alumno2/$', crea_alumno.as_view(),name='alumno2'),
```

models.py

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apellido1 = models.CharField('Primer apellido',max_length=50)
    apellido2 = models.CharField('Segundo apellido',max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("Correo electronico",null=True)
    repetidor = models.BooleanField()
    curs = models.ManyToManyField(Curso, blank=True, related_name="Historico_de_cursos")
    Nivel = models.ManyToManyField('Nivel', through = 'Completado',through_fields=('Alumno','Nivel'))
    Practica = models.ManyToManyField('Practica', through = 'Nota',through_fields=('Alumno','Practica'))
    Curso = models.ManyToManyField('Curso',through = 'Curso_alumno',through_fields=('Alumno','Curso'))


    def __str__(self):
        return self.dni
```

the html only display the save button, is not loading the create form. The html is inside the template folders thats why I have this urls.

**EDIT:** 
I have removed the template I had also

```
url(r'^alumno2/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='alumno2.html'),name='alumno2'),
```

and I'm not sure if i need to put this in the url.py so now I only have the view and is unable to find my template withouth that

Comment: Have you created `.html` file inside `Templates` folder?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani yes, I can acces to the html but didn't display any form only the save button

Comment: ALL is correct here, I think the missing one is `LoginRequiredMixin` in view before passing `CreateView`, I don't know that this is the actual reason, although you can try this.

Comment: @PallaviSharma I'm not using login sistem at the momment because I'm having hard times, so everybody can make everything

Comment: Try removing the `/` in `template_name = '/alumno2.html'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line

```
url(r'^alumno2/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='alumno2.html'),name='alumno2'),
```

from your `urls.py` and only keep this one:

```
url(r'^alumno2/$', crea_alumno.as_view(),name='alumno2'),
```

And inside your view, remove the `/` in the template name: instead of

```
template_name = '/alumno2.html'
```

Use

```
template_name = 'alumno2.html'
```

And replace `CreateView` with `FormView` as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)